# UIRefreshControl weirdness

Tags: ios, ios6, interface-builder, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

Just started to use "UIRefreshControl" today, and noticed some weird things.

If I created the UIRefreshControl in InterfaceBuilder, and wire it all up, my selector never gets called. IB says that the control should fire on the "value changed" message, and should call my code, but never does.

So I abandoned doing this in Interface Builder, and just decided to do this in the code. Not too many lines. So I put this code inside of my "viewDidLoad" routine:

```
self.refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(doStuff:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
NSMutableParagraphStyle* paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to refresh" attributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle}];
```

It draws fine, but the refresh-control is visible when the view first appears. I'd prefer that it not be visible until the user actually pulls down on the table. I'm making a call to a web-service, and wait for the results to come back, then I populate the table. So, you only see the control for a second or two. But it just looks weird.

So, the questions are:
1. Is this a known bug that you can't wire up the control solely from Interface Builder?
2. Is there a way to add this control to the table-view controller, without it appearing until the user actually wants to see it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add a refresh control, or declare one in your viewController.  Adding pull-to-refresh is a two-step process.
Step 1: In your storyboard, go to your tableViewController and, where it says "Refreshing", select "Enabled".
Step 2: Add the following code to your tableViewController.m file, in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(refresh)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

That's the entire process, other than doing stuff in your -refresh method.  There's no more to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a bug with the `UIRefreshControl` that the action is never called. Keith Harrison talks about this in his blog entry [UIRefreshControl Fun and Games](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/06/18/uirefreshcontrol-fun-and-games.html?utm_source=iOS%20Dev%20Weekly&utm_campaign=d888c696dd-iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_99&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_7bda94b7ca-d888c696dd-298114649):

> Investigating with the debugger it seems that the refresh method is
>   never called. I can only assume that for some reason the storyboard is
>   not properly connecting the UIRefreshControl to our action or is
>   having some other strange interaction with the
>   UIControlEventValueChanged event. I have filed a bug report with Apple
>   ([rdar://14178445](http://openradar.appspot.com/14178445)) but there is also a simple workaround you can use.

The workaround is as described by @AMayes.

Comment: I had this bug when my view controller had "free size" = 1000px. When I changed it back to fixed, refresh started to work correctly.

Comment: removing the  "freeform size" in storyboard is what finally fixed it! Thanks!